# Align the text to the center of the spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

How to align the text to the center of the spinner?

[image]

code that I am using:

```
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/s_change_type"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         style="@style/Spinner"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Spinner:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      android:singleLine="true"
      style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:textAlignment="inherit"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

Style used by spinner:

```
   <style name="Spinner"
       parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/margin_general_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/margin_general_right</item>
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: try `android:textAlignment="center"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `TextView` write:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Instead of:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: that should do it